# HubControl: Different files for each hub section on windows phone 8.1

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I cannot find any information about how to structure the hubControl a little bit better. All the examples I can find put all the information in *one* xaml file. Am I missing something? I don't think that this gives you an easily maintainable code. The hub template creates the following code (stopping after the first section to abbreviate but there are four more to come in the sample code):

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Hub x:Name="Hub" x:Uid="Hub" Header="application name" Background="{ThemeResource HubBackgroundImageBrush}">
            <HubSection x:Uid="HubSection1" Header="SECTION 1" DataContext="{Binding Groups}" HeaderTemplate="{ThemeResource HubSectionHeaderTemplate}">
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ListView
                        ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                        ItemClick="GroupSection_ItemClick"
                        ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.ExitElementContainer="True">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,27.5">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </DataTemplate>
            </HubSection>
```

How is it possible to have each section in a different xaml file?

Or are there other ways to get a better code structure?

I did something like this with the pivot control by adding the pivot items in code but the hub control does not have a content property and messing around with content templates seems a little bit too ugly. Does anyone have an idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Although I am still struggeling with passing the data context/ viewModel in some cases I guess the simple solution is to just create a new file (user control or page) and use something like

```
<HubSection Header="About">
    <DataTemplate>
        <local:AboutPage />
    </DataTemplate>
</HubSection>
```

Thanks to everybody who had a look!

Comment: Once you figure out how to pass the datacontext / VM, please edit your answer for future readers :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a [`DataTemplateSelector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx).  This allows you to write a custom mapping from instance to template in code.